# Moving 60 d correlation without for/while loop

Tags: r, time-series, moving-average

I have a matrix with two columns. I want to calculate "running" 60-day correlation between the two columns. Is it possible to do this R way, ie without using for/while loop.

basically my t day calc will be based on  (t-60:t) and t-1 day will be (t-61:t-1) and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your matrix is m then...

```
b <- 60
sapply( b:nrow(m), function(t) cor(m[(t-b):t,] )
```